# returning a vector or passing by reference

Tags: performance, function, c++11, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm writing an ODE integrator that evaluates dy/dx at each step and doesn't need it afterwards. it seems that it would be faster to allocate the space only ones and just use that space so that I don't spend time allocating a new dydx vector. does compiler optimize this?
In other words, which one is better?

1)

```
vector<double> dydx(const vector<double>&x) {
  vector<double> dydx_tmp(x.size());
  for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size()/2; ++i) {
    dydx_tmp[2*i] = -x[2*i+1]; 
    dydx_tmp[2*i+1] = x[2*i];
  } 
  return dydx_tmp;
}
```

or
2), where dydx is already allocated and just needs an update

```
void update_dydx(vector<double> & dydx, const vector<double> &x) {
  for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size()/2; ++i) {
    dydx[2*i] = -x[2*i+1]; 
    dydx[2*i+1] = x[2*i];
  } 
}
```

there is also a case of
3)

```
vector<double> dydx_by_v(vector<double> x) {
  vector<double> dydx_tmp(x.size());
  for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size()/2; ++i) {
    dydx_tmp[2*i] = -x[2*i+1]; 
    dydx_tmp[2*i+1] = x[2*i];
  } 
  return dydx_tmp;
}
```

that follows http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/ but in this case, it doesn't matter because `x`'s memory is used later for output so it won't be used by compiler's RVO.

Comment: Is your vector really just two floating point numbers?

Comment: @delnan it ranges from 2 to thousands, it can be a compile- or a run-time parameter. the operation is on the whole vector. I just tried to keep it simple

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimate answer to all performance related questions is profiling your whole app on hardware same(or at least similar) to what it will be running on in production environment, but here's my three cents of theorycrafting:

- passing by value in option 3) doesn't make any sense
- vector dydx_tmp(x.size()); <- this causes default constructing(aka zeroing) your vector. use vector dydx; dydx.reserve(x.size()); and then emplace_back() in the loop(adding _temp to your name is useless - everyone can see it's local)
- option 2) involves input parameter which is consider bad style and there will be no copy in option 1) anyway(as explained in article you linked), so 1) is best option

Comment: because `x` has only 2 elements. it can also have thousands. i'm just making things simple

Comment: so your function actually looks like for(i = 0; i < x.size()/2; ++i){dydx[2*i] = -x[2*i+1]; dydx[2*i+1] = x[2*i];} instead of just 2 assignments? if so, edit your question, it makes quite a difference

Comment: there is no copy in option 1) but it still needs to allocate the new space. option 2 doesn't need to do that. wouldn't option 2 be faster?

Comment: dxdy has to be allocated somewhere. if it's allocated just before call to that function, then 1) is better because of already mentioned reasons. but if you are calling your func in a loop and you can allocate dxdy just once for all iterations, then sure, 2) is better. but you didn't mention that in your question

Comment: ok, I updated the question. I meant that in 2, it's already allocated

Comment: see my previous comment - if you can get away with one allocation, it will obviously be faster than N allocations. what else do you expect to hear?

Comment: probably not, since it's dynamic allocation based on value returned by function, but back to first line of my answer - just check it with your app, your compiler on your architecture